# CSS: Inline-Display: Using DIV why am I getting space on 2nd DIV?

Tags: css, html

Pretty simple page. Want to use inline-display instead of float. Set this up a few times now, but, for some reason on this page it's dropping down the menu div when I set the height of the logo div.

demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFyCm/)

HTML

```
<div id="topbar">
<div class="item" id="logo"></div>
<div class="item" id="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #topbar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
#topbar .item {
    line-height: 91px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #063;
}
#topbar #logo {
    background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30%;
    height: 91px;
}
#topbar #menu {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Probably simple solution or simple error from my side but cannot see it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I didn't see you don't want float solution.

Comment: And that's why we use `floats`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top` on the menu and it should look good. Making your styles for the `#menu` the following:

```
#topbar #menu {
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zbGWM/)

Answer (score 0):

you should vertically align your images (logo). By default it's aligned with default text line.

So, update your css rule

```
#topbar #logo {
    background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30%;
    height: 91px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tZNw4/29/

Answer (score 0):

not able to understand why this is happening but here is solution
[changed display](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6ej/)

```
#topbar {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
display: table;
}

#topbar .item {
line-height: 91px;
display: table-cell;
background-color: #063;
height: 91px;
}
```